# after logging into my jenkins dashboard i cant find dot jenkins file in my root user..how to get it?

Tags: xml, jenkins

I was logged in to my jenkins dashboard but the *.jenkins* file should be created in the root user. I can't find it in my root user. I want to get one in my root user.

Comment: Verify your Jenkins process is running with which user. If that is not running with root user then you cant see that .jenkins file.

Comment: iam running jenkins through tomcat...the same root user if check..it was not there